# dynamically adding servlet from external file, Tomcat7

Tags: java, servlets, tomcat7, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to dynamically add a servlet from an external file (compiled .class file) running tomcat7 server

here's my code

```
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent;
import javax.servlet.ServletContextListener;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.util.ClassLoaderRepository;



public class ConListenerImlp implements ServletContextListener{


    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        ServletContext context =  arg0.getServletContext();
        final ServletRegistration.Dynamic dn=context.addServlet("test","C:\\Users\\Learning\\workspace\\Server\\build\\classes\\Test.class");
        dn.setAsyncSupported(true);
        dn.addMapping("/test");



    }


}
```

when i call servlet "test" I get a ClassNotFoundException

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: C:\Users\Learning\workspace\Server\build\classes\Test.class
```

any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Read the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet(java.lang.String,javax.servlet.Servlet)) for the method .It addresses your concern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29):

> Adds the servlet with the given name and **class name** to this servlet context.
>
> The registered servlet may be further configured via the returned ServletRegistration object.
>
> The specified className **will be loaded using the classloader associated with the application represented by this ServletContext**.

(emphasis mine)

This method expects a class name (something like `com.yourcompany.yourapp.TestServlet`), not a file path. And the class must be present in the classpath of the webapp, i.e. in `WEB-INF/classes` or one of the jars of `WEB-INF/lib`.

Side note: you should never put classes in the default package.